# Standards for displaying partial email address?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, recovery

I have a recovery system that I'm working on, and I would like to implement a message after going through the recovery process that would notify the person of a partial email address that the account recovery email has been sent to. An example of this would be:

Thank you, your password reset link has been emailed to j*********e@domain.com.

My question is, are there any industry standards for displaying partial emails in messages like this? Facebook uses the method I have in the message above, but I have seen other sites using different forms as well, sometimes blanking out everything except the last 3 characters of the email + domain, and some blanking out everything except the first 3 characters + domain. The almighty Google fails me on searching for a "standard" for displaying partial emails, maybe someone here has some information?

Comment: Don't think there is such thing as standard for partial email address, don't even think any1 though about it till now :) Just use it as you like.

Comment: Ok, so here comes the million dollar question. How can you accomplish this without running into major issues? I'm not seeing a solution in the form of a Regex, and I'm not entirely sure that this can be done in the ViewModel, or the Controller without having something too complex.